# show a modal dialog and stop all others event

Tags: jquery, events

I am trying to open a modal dialog when the visitor choose **Cape Cod Local Van Delivery $1.00**

```
<select name="ShippingSpeedChoice" onchange="this.form.submit();" style="">
    <option value="0">PLEASE SELECT</option>
    <option value='101' >Free Shipping (UPS Ground) </option>
    <option value='1001'>Cape Cod Local Van Delivery $1.00 </option>
</select>
```

my script :

```
$("#v65-cart-shipping-details select").change(function(event) {
if (this.value == '1001'){
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
    });
}
});
```

the modoal show for few secondes and soudanly the page reload due to `onchange="this.form.submit();"`

I need to stop this event until I close the modal dialog

Comment: Get rid of `onchange="this.form.submit();"` and submit the form in the onclose handler of the dialog.

Comment: exactly what i was thinking... +1 for you Archer

Answer (score 0):

remove the onchange event from your HTML

```
<select name="ShippingSpeedChoice" style="">
    <option value="0">PLEASE SELECT</option>
    <option value='101' >Free Shipping (UPS Ground) </option>
    <option value='1001'>Cape Cod Local Van Delivery $1.00 </option>
</select>
```

and put the jQuery like this:

```
$("#v65-cart-shipping-details select").change(function(event) {
    if (this.value == '1001'){
       $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
           height: 140,
           modal: true,
           close:function(){
              // form submit action here
           }
       });
    }
});
```